# How to make afterInsert / afterUpdate GORM method an async methods

Tags: performance, grails, asynchronous, aop

Grails users know that Data access layer of this framework offer an AOP programming via seperation cross-layer from other soft layers : `afterInsert`, `afterUpdate`,`beforeInsert` .... methods .

```
   class Person{

    def afterInsert(){
        //... Will be executed after inserting record into Person table
     }
  }
```

I search on the type of this methods vis-a-vis Constructor(instantiation ): **Asynchronous**  or **not** . And i don't find the answer .

My question : if not, Does GORM will be breaked if we force those methods to be asynchronous.

### UPDATE :

Indeed, we want send mails without using a ready plugin as we have our own API.

Comment: There are a great number of ways to run Async processes/code from any of those events. It depends on how you wan to do so. Sending a JMS message to be processed comes to mind, using GPars or Async features inside Grails also is an option. Your question is too broad. What have you tried, and what didn't work about what you tried?

Comment: sending mails . this is what i want

Comment: If you want to send async e-mails then you can use the Async Mail Plugin. Which you can use from any of those methods or anywhere else in your Grails application. http://grails.org/plugin/asynchronous-mail

Comment: I recommend you read about Asynchronous programming in Grails. This way you can call your own mailing service/methods/whatever from within those methods asynchronously. http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/async.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a great number of ways to accomplish what you are looking for, and without knowing all your requirements it's difficult to give you a solution that meets all of them. However, based on your question and the comments provided you could use the built in [Asynchronous features](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/async.html) in Grails to accomplish this.

This is just a sketch/example of something I came up with off the top of my head.

```
import static grails.async.Promises.*
class Person {
  ...
  def afterUpdate() {
    def task1 = task {
      // whatever code you need to run goes here.
    }
    onComplete([task1]) {
      // anything you want to run after the task completes, or nothing at all.
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

This is just one option. Again, there are a lot of options available to you. You could send a JMS message instead and have it processed on a different machine. You could use some type of eventing system, you could even use Spring AOP and Thread pools and abstract this even further. It depends on what your requirements are, and what your capabilities are as well.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how does this works internally? ... does this uses an internal ThreadPoolExecutor behind the scenes or something like this?

Comment: Ever consider the fact Grails is open source and you can read how it's implemented?: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/tree/master/grails-async

Comment: Sure. in fact i am usual reader of the Grails core code, but in many cases there are many sources of information apart from the code ... i have just asked for good sources to learn about this since you seems to have deep knowledge. Thanks for the link.

Comment: You're more than welcome. Aside from the documentation regarding Async the source code is the best information out there. I'm not aware of anything else regarding this topic. Except, perhaps the source for GPars.